# Bayesian urn questions

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

There are two urns, each with four ping-pong balls. In one urn,
three of the balls are red, and one is white; in the other, three are white,
and one is red. Without knowing which urn you are choosing, you reach
inside and draw out, at random, a red ball. You put the ball back into the
urn, mix up the contents, and repeat the experiment (remember there are
four balls once more inside the urn). Again you draw out a red ball. Based
on this two-part experiment, what is the probability that the urn you chose
is the one with the three red balls in it?

I'm not entirely too sure how to start this. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You can start by saying how, without any given data, you have a 50% chance of choosing either urn. And because the probability of pulling two reds in a row is greater in the urn with three reds, you can assume the probability should be higher than 50%

Comment: Well, right. I understand that. I just don't know how to find the exact probability by using Bayes' Theorem.

Comment: By using Bayes' Theorem, what I am getting is that $P(\mathbf{Urn1} | RR) = \frac{(P(RR|\mathbf{Urn1})) * P(\mathbf{Urn1})}{P(RR)}$. Where $P(RR|\mathbf{Urn1}) = 9/16 $ and $P(\mathbf{Urn1}) = 1/2$. However I cannot come up with a value for $P(RR)$

Comment: Actually I think I figured out. I'll put it in the answer section in a minute

Answer (score 2):

Just hints, as requested:

Let $U_i$ be the event that you are drawing from urn $i$ and let $R_i$ be the event that you draw a red ball on your ith draw (with replacement).

Here are some questions to guide your thinking:

1. If you know you are drawing from a particular urn, with replacement, what is the applicable probability model for drawing red balls?
2. Lets assume $P(U_i)=0.5$, what is the probability of drawing two red balls, overall? (Hint: this is the denominator of Bayes theorem). Think about the law of total probability: Your events can be partitioned into "draws from $U_1$" and "draws from $U_20$"

Let me know if you need more, but the above should get you to the solution.

Comment: 1. If I am drawing from the urn with 3 red balls, then the probability of drawing two reds in a row would be 3/4 *3/4 = 9/16.


2. This is where I'm stuck. Would I combine both urns into one? As in, choosing two red balls in a row given 4 red balls and 4 white balls?

Comment: @dubbler26 yep...what probability model would best fit the situation of drawing from a particular urn?

Comment: @dubbler26 Hint: geometric, hyergeometric, or binomial?

Comment: @dubbler26 so, do you know what Bayes' Theorem looks like? you need to know that $P(A)P(B|A)=P(A\cap B)$

Comment: @dubbler26 to get $P(R_1\cap R_2)$ you need to use the law of total probability (the denominator of Bayes' Theorem)

Comment: Ah, ok. So you'd use total probability in the denominator? As in the probability of drawing two reds from urn 1 multiplied by the probability of picking urn1 and then adding the same thing for urn 2.

Comment: @dubbler26 really try to understand the Venn Diagram of Bayes' Theorem. Ok, I'm done blasting you with comments. Let me know if you need more hints.

Comment: @dubbler26 exactly!

Comment: Haha, just saw the previous comments. Ok, I think I got it now.

Comment: Ok, great! Baye's is not so bad once you know what the denominator and numerator actually represent.

Comment: To the downvoter: Any reason here?

Answer (score 0):

By using Bayes' Theorem, what I am getting is that $$P(\mathbf{Urn1} | RR) = \frac{(P(RR|\mathbf{Urn1})) * P(\mathbf{Urn1})}{P(RR)}$$ Where $P(RR|\mathbf{Urn1}) = 9/16 $ and $P(\mathbf{Urn1}) = 1/2$.

To find $P(RR)$ we use the law of total probability: $$P(RR) =P(RR|\mathbf{Urn1}) *P(\mathbf{Urn1}) + P(RR|\mathbf{Urn2}) * P(\mathbf{Urn2})$$

We know that $P(RR|\mathbf{Urn2}) = 1/16$ and $P(\mathbf{Urn2})$ is also $1/2$

Therefore we get that $$P(RR) = (9/16)(1/2) + (1/16)(1/2) = .3125 $$

Plug this back into the final equation to get $$P(\mathbf{Urn1} | RR) = \frac{(9/16)* (1/2)}{.3125} = 0.9$$

There is a **90%** chance that you picked the urn with 3 red balls in it.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I just saw this after reaching the same conclusion from Bey's hints. Thanks for the help!